# How to Get All NFTs Owned by an Address on my custom blockchain

Tags: nft, evm, nodejs, blockchain-fork, api

on mumbai lets say, i can use the alchemy sdk, where i input the network name and then call the functions easilly,

however if the network is testnetwork with a chain id of 1234 and public RPC of : "https://tetnetwork1234.com"

how can i fetch all the owned nfts of an address on that custom blockchain?

Comment: 1. Question: What NFT standard are you working with, ERC721 or ?? 
2. Question: You want a list of all NFT's or just their tokeIds? (Example: first minted NFT has tokenId 0) So if I own only first 3 minted tokens you would get array: [0,1,2]

Comment: 1-all of them combined, all the ERC20 and ERC721 and ERC1155 from all the smart contracts and not only one
2-prefferably all their info, so token id token address and tokenURI

Answer (score 0):

**At specific point in time**

Calculating balances involves tracking every transfer-event (from + to) that ever happened to that account.

In web3 you would do something like this to get all transfer-events for a specific timerange. See [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#getpastlogs) for other ways to filter (e.g.: on contract address)

```
const transfers = await web3.eth.getPastLogs({
  fromBlock: <from block>,
  toBlock: <to block>,,
  topics: ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"], // transfer topic
})
```

Afterwards be sure to filter out all ERC-20 events, which also makes use of this same event-signature. To only get NFT transfers look for returned events with 4 indexed topics (instead of the normal 3 for ERC-20)

Afterwards, use `web3.eth.abi.decodeLog` or similar to get de decoded values: from_address/to_address/token_id

Tally up all transfers where  is the 'to_address' and, subtract where  is the 'from_address'

**For current time, but only if contract supports it**

```
// create contract based on NFT contract-address + ABI
// Afterwards do:
const result = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress)
```